# MIPS - Branching convention with bne

Tags: assembly, mips, branch-prediction

In lecture, our professor said that there is a reason behind using `bne` in branching rather than using `beq`(and left us to figure it out), like the example shown below.

```
if ( i == j )
    i++ ;
j-- ;
```

which compiles down to

```
bne  $r1, $r2, L1        # branch if ! ( i == j ) 
addi $r1, $r1, 1         # i++ 
L1: addi $r2, $r2, -1    # j--
```

Also, [in this link](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/cond.html), it is also being implied that it is a *convention* in MIPS assembly to implement conditional branching in *negation* manner. My best bet was, it was for keeping the common case simple - and therefore fast-, because intuitively if we were checking for equality then we would expect it to be more likely to become equal, and therefore PC to branch when it is **not** equal. I think I just pushed hard to make it reasonable, but I still couldn't distinguish the core difference between implementing it in `beq` or in `bne`. I would really appreciate if someone explains why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what the code would look like if you *had* used `beq`. You might end up with this:

```
beq $r1, $r2, L1
L2: addi $r2, $r2, -1 # j--
...
...
L1: addi $r1, $r1, 1 #i++
j L2
```

Or this:

```
beq $r1, $r2, L1
addi $r2, $r2, -1 # j--
j L2
L1: addi $r1, $r1, 1 #i++
addi $r2, $r2, -1 # j--
L2:
```

In either case you'd have an extra branch in one of the execution paths, compared to if you had used `bne` at the beginning.

Comment: Aha I think the problem not only putting a branch but is writing one more instruction to fulfill the overall functionality.

Comment: Which may be not a preferred because takes much space in instruction memory. However I wonder, what if we were using if-else ? It uses again the same negation pattern even though, I believe, we necessarily don't need to.